# How to run multiple commands in a file

Tags: linux

In Linux, I am trying to create a file that will run an executable for a network build to remote host boxes on our network.

Before I can do the network build though, I have to run a few commands, so I've created a file named Network_Build and entered my commands in it, but the only command that will run is the first one, then it stops.

Here is what I have in the file:

```
#!/bin/bash
su mcc
xhost+
su root
eval $(ssh-agent);ssh-add
ssh-add /home/ccttsa/.ssh/id_dsa
./site_network_install.sh
```

I want to just be able to enter ./Network_Build to run all commands in the file, but when I do all it does is change user to mcc then stops.

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26074/is-there-a-way-to-stop-having-to-write-sudo-for-every-little-thing-in-linux

Comment: It doesn't stop, it's waiting for `su` to exit so it can continue with the other commands.

Comment: Adding the commands separated by semi-colon `;` adjacent to the respective sudo should help here!

Answer (score 0):

I've rewritten your script. The below should work.

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo -su mcc xhost+;
sudo -su root eval $(ssh-agent);ssh-add;ssh-add /home/ccttsa/.ssh/id_dsa;./site_network_install.sh
```

Hope this helps!